Copy attribute frome edge to face
I have a question that is probably very basic for most of you, but that I'm stuck on.
I have a starting mesh that contains a edge marked by an attribute (in this case “test”). After extruding the edge of the mesh, I'd like to “transfer” the attribute of the marked edge to its extruded face


(Using Blender 3.6.8)
The attribute is already "transferred" to the extruded face:

1. The Store Named Attribute node is tagging True a single edge chosen through its Selection socket.
2. The Extrude Mesh node set in Edges mode is preserving the attribute value when it is copying edges before translating these.
3. The attribute value for connecting edges (those "vertical" in the demonstration case) is copied from the original vertex they are extruded from. Because of special interpolation rules for boolean, such a vertex is True if any of its connected edges is True.
4. So, all 4 edges of the face of interest are tagged True. Consequently, because of the same rules, the face is tagged True.
NB: Beware that if Float instead of Boolean type is used, with 0 instead of False and 1 instead of True, the "vertical" edges value is $0.5=\frac{1}{2}(0+1)$  and the face of interest value is $0.75=\frac{1}{4}(1+1+0.5+0.5)$, not $1$.
Resources: 

Thank you @StefLAncien
I feel stupid. I didn't even think to try if the attribute had been propagated to the face. And I discovered that the attribute is also propagated to the points.

@Humfred if this answer works then please upvote and accept it, so it will be removed from the pending questions.

May I recommend to apply this : What should I do when someone answers my question? ?

@StefLAncien Thank you for advising, I'm new to using StackExchange.
